# Как зажать клавишу в pyautogui python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

очень долго перечитывал документацию по pyautogui, но нигде не нашел как можно зажать кнопку клавиатуры. Может быть у кого-нибудь есть рукописные функции?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как сделать long click в pyautogui (python 3)?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1147342/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-long-click-%d0%b2-pyautogui-python-3)

Comment: я удалил тот вопрос

Comment: так вот же - >>> pyautogui.keyDown('shift')  # hold down the shift key
>>> pyautogui.press('left')     # press the left arrow key
>>> pyautogui.press('left')     # press the left arrow key
>>> pyautogui.press('left')     # press the left arrow key
>>> pyautogui.keyUp('shift')    # release the shift key

Answer (score 0):

```
import pyautogui
pyautogui.keyDown('shift')  #Зажимаем клавишу "Shift"
pyautogui.keyUp('shift')    #Отпускаем клавишу "Shift"
```